# Julia Symbolics can't simplify derivative expressions

Tags: julia, symbolic-math, derivative, simplify

I am using the Symbolics package in Julia, and it seems to not be simplifying derivatives of expressions.

E.g.:

```
@variables r
Dr = Differential(r)
simplify(expand_derivatives(Dr((2/r)^2)))
```

results in

```
(-4(2 / (r^2))) / r
```

If I instead create the derivative expression by hand, then simplify works great

```
simplify((-4*(2 / (r^2))) / r)
```

gives

```
-8 / (r^3)
```

as expected.

Why doesn't simplify work correctly on expressions created from differentiation?

Comment: What is `Dr` in your code? Is it `Dr = Differential(r)`

Comment: Correct! I've added that clarification in.

Answer (score 2):

Use `expand=true`. Set up code:

```
using Symbolics
@variables r
Dr = Differential(r)
```

And now:

```
julia> simplify(expand_derivatives(Dr((2/r)^2)); expand=true)
-8 / (r^3)
```

Note that `simplify((-4(2 / (r^2))) / r)` worked because `(-4(2 / (r^2))) / r` was simplified before reaching that function:

```
julia> -4(2 / (r^2)) / r
-8 / (r^3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Question: is it necessary to do expand=true? This has an annoying effect that (r-2)^2 -> r^2 - 4r + 4. I would rather avoid that outcome.

Comment: Doesn't work for things such as: `@variables A; test = 1//2*sqrt(A); Symbolics.simplify(test, expand=true)`

Comment: @dwong for this example you get `(1//2)*sqrt(A)` what else would you expect?

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel  It's supposed to be `(1//2)*sqrt(4*A)` next time try using some context and ask whether the comment made a mistake and needs editing rather than being obnoxious

Comment: In your code you are not calculating a derivative so the question what you expect is a totally valid question to ask. I did not mean to be obnoxious - simply if you say that something does not work for you, please provide the input and either the desired or observed/wrong output. Perhaps you meant `expand_derivatives(Differential(A)(test))` which yields  `1 / (4sqrt(A))` what is I guess you were expecting? Please be specific.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel again, "is a totally valid question to ask." Again, no and you're being obnoxious. Second, the input code was already provided and a comment after shows what needs to be edited to repeat the problem. The results should simply to `2*sqrt(A)` which it doesn't . If you can't even bother to read a question why even bother reaponding and being obnoxious?